# arithmetic intensity of zgemv versus dgemv/sgemv?

Tags: math, cpu-architecture, hpc, blas, intel-mkl

The ***arithmetic intensity*** of `sgemv` (or `dgemv`) is derived in this set of exercises (https://florian.world/wp-content/uploads/FM-High-Performance-Computing-I-Assignment-1.pdf) to be:
`0.5 / (1+c)`, where `c` is a constant.

I was wondering whether `zgemv`, the complex-counterpart of these operations, has the same arithmetic intensity as the purely real ones?

***I think as follows:***

A complex-complex multiplication of the type `(a+b*i) * (c+d*i)`, where `i^2=-1`, is equal to `(ac - cd) + i*(bc + ad)`, so there are 4 multiplications and two additions, for a total of 6 ops. In contrast, to multiply two purely real numbers, only one multiplication is needed.

To load a complex number, two double precision numbers have to be loaded, so this increases the memory traffic by 2 as well.

In total, the arithmetic intensity shall be roughly 3 times larger?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is correct except I think you missed the additions : a matrix multiplication do `O(n^3)` additions and `O(n^3)` multiplications. Complex additions requires twice more additions than real ones. In the end, ~8 ops are needed for a complex FMA while this is 2 for real FMA. So the ratio between the two is 4 and the arithmetic intensity shall be roughly 2 times larger (because of the twice bigger data size).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I appreciate it. Yes, totally missed the additions.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Note this is gemV not gemM.  gemV only touches each matrix element once (although does touch the vector elements many times).  So all the cool cache-blocking techniques that let SGEMV and DGEMV mostly bottleneck on FMA throughput not memory bandwidth don't apply.  Only unrolling techniques like loading a SIMD vector from the vector and using it with multiple rows or columns from the matrix to get closer to 1 load per FMA (how modern x86 CPUs are balanced) instead of 2 loads per FMA for a straight dot product.  (Alder Lake actually supports 3 vector loads per 2 FMAs.)

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Also, are you counting FMA as two operations?  For the CPU it's 1 uop, even though we normally count it as two FLOPs.  What normally matters for performance is computational intensity in terms of the CPU pipeline(s), not in terms of FLOPs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, as two operations, because it is about FLOPs and on-the-paper estimations independent of the CPU used. Some old CPU do not have FMA instructions (my notebook CPU for example ^^") and I think FMA instructions may be used here to compute a part of the expression (1 FMA + 1 standard MUL) so it is better to count it as two operations I think.

Comment: @PeterCordes Here, performance is dependent on the layout as you pointed out in your answer while theoretical computational intensity is independent from that. I consider the OP question as a theoretical one, or otherwise I expect the code to be provided including the data layout ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Given the [hpc] tag, I decided to focus on hardware suitable for HPC, which these days means FMA.  But yeah, on other hardware it would be different.  As usual, the right thing to compute depends on what you're going to do with the result, i.e. what you really want to know and why.

Comment: Many thanks to both - I am learning from these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gemv is a matrix-vector product, so each element of the result is a dot-product of the vector and a row or column of the matrix.  That's a multiply *and add*, not just multiply.

On modern hardware, that's done with one FMA (Fused Multiply-Add) for about the same cost as one multiply, effectively getting the add part for free.

An optimized ZGEMV would also use some FMAs for the complex multiply and add, like 2 multiplies, 2 FMAs for just a complex multiply.

Or four FMAs if adding to existing accumulators of real and imaginary parts.  (Creating two long dependency chains, so you'd need to [unroll more to hide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction), although you do already have instruction-level parallelism between the FMAs that add into the real vs. imaginary parts.)

**So with FMA, it should be about 2x the computational intensity: 4x as many FMAs for 2x as many loads per "element".**

---

This is assuming the complex numbers are stored with separate arrays of real and imaginary parts, so SIMD loads can get vectors of `[r0, r1, r2, r3]` and `[i0, i1, i2, i3]`, keeping the problem pure vertical with no shuffling like you'd need with a `[r0,i0, r1,i1, ...]` interleaved layout (Array of Structs aka AoS).  If you need shuffles, then computational intensity is higher, but it's not "useful" work, and it's potentially on different execution units than the ones that can run FMA.